# Apex Class to Update Stage of Opportunity by Completeing Field on the record

Tags: salesforce, apex

I've been editing an Apex Class that is supposed to update the Opportunity.StageName when specific fields are completed, however no matter what I do I can't seem to get the field to update to 'Booked'. All stages preceding and proceeding work eg. If I update the fields that meet the 'Closed Won' criteria it updates. It just appears to be that particular Stage.

There doesn't seem to be any issues with the formatting so I'm at a loss as to why it doesn't work.

```
        {
        opp.Override_Stage__c = true;
        opp.StageName = 'Candidates';

        if((opp.Site_Requirements_Sent_To_Client__c == 'Yes' && opp.Client_Confirmed_Requirements__c == 'Yes') || opp.Site_Requirements_Sent_To_Client__c == 'N/A')
        {
            opp.StageName = 'Quote';

                if(opp.Quote_Accepted__c == 'Yes')
                {
                    opp.StageName = 'Awaiting Invoice'; 

                        if(opp.Invoice_Created__c == 'Yes')
                        {
                            opp.StageName = 'Invoiced';
                    
                            if(opp.PO_Received__c == 'Yes')
                            {
                                opp.StageName = 'Awaiting Payment';

                                    if(opp.Payment_In_Full_Received__c == 'Yes')
                                    {
                                        opp.StageName = 'Paid';

                                            if(opp.Training_Provider__c== 'Online')
                                            {
                                                opp.StageName = 'Booked';
                        
                                                    if(opp.Surveys_Printed__c == 'Yes')
                                                    {
                                                        opp.StageName = 'Closed Won';
                                                    }
                                            }
                                     }
                            }
                        }
                }
            else if(opp.Quote_Accepted__c == 'No')
            {
                opp.StageName = 'Closed Lost';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have field history tracking on the field? Can there be something that sets the stage to Booked and then immediately back (workflow/flow/process builder?) Have you tried using debug log to spot if there's more than 1 update statement? Put something stupid like `System.debug('I am here'); next to that line and see if it appears in the debug log.

Answer (score 0):

Constants are Case-sensitive. I think you should check the field value of opp.Training_Provider__c. If it is predefined better to copy the API name of the value in code.